# How to use variables defined in inventory

Tags: ansible

i have multiple servers and on each of server have multiple containers in my inventory. some servers would be in one group, some in other group and i want to specify for each container url variable. 
my inventory:

can i loop over these URL's like a with_dict? and if yes, how?

my inventory:

```
all:
  hosts:
    <1st-server-ip>:
      ansible_host: <IP>
    <2nd-server-ip>:
      ansible_host: <IP>
    <3rd-server-ip>:
      ansible_host: <IP>
  children:
    <1st-GROUP>:
      hosts:
        <1st-server-ip>:
          <containers>:
            <app-1>:
              url: '<URL>'
            <app-2>:
              url: '<URL>'
            <app-3>:
              url: '<URL>'
    <2nd-GROUP>:
      hosts:
        <2nd-server-ip>:
          <containers>:
            <app-4>:
              url: '<URL>'
            <app-5>:
              url: '<URL>'
    <3rd-GROUP>:
      hosts:
        <3rd-server-ip>:
          <containers>:
            <app-6>:
              url: '<URL>'
            <app-7>:
              url: '<URL>'
            <app-8>:
              url: '<URL>'
```

Comment: Hi Jakub, welcome to SO. Please make your question more concrete, with perhaps a smaller example inventory and more importantly the expected output or behavior you're looking for. It is also traditional that you provide **code** that you have already tried, rather than asking SO to author code for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) is able to reduce the structure to the list of lists which can be iterated with [include_tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_tasks_module.html#include-tasks-dynamically-include-a-task-list).

The play below

```
- include_tasks: loop-url.yml
  loop: "{{ all.children|json_query('*.hosts.*.containers[]') }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: outer_item
```

with included tasks

```
> cat loop-url.yml
- debug:
    msg: "key: {{ item.key }} value: {{ item.value.url }}"
  loop: "{{ outer_item|dict2items }}"
```

gives (grep msg):

```
"msg": "key: app-7 value: URL"
"msg": "key: app-6 value: URL"
"msg": "key: app-8 value: URL"
"msg": "key: app-5 value: URL"
"msg": "key: app-4 value: URL"
"msg": "key: app-3 value: URL"
"msg": "key: app-2 value: URL"
"msg": "key: app-1 value: URL"
```

(tag signs <> were removed from the data)